# python - dataframe.loc, boolean on index

Tags: python, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe:

```
df = |0 10|
     |1 20|
     |2 30|
```

I am trying to return a new dataframe, `df2 = df['INDEXNAME' < 2]`, so that it returns only the first two rows.

I've tried:

```
df.loc[df<100]
df.loc[df['INDEXNAME']<100]
```

but these are giving me a

> KeyError: 'INDEXNAME'

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: what is the name of your column with the data? use it insead of the INDEXNAME - I believe that is just a placeholder

Comment: the column with the data is named "DATA", and I've named the index "INDEXNAME".   I realize how brutal names these are...  mucking around.

Answer (score 2):

You can use query:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'value':[10,20,30]}, index = [20,2,0])
df.index.name = "beta"

df.query("beta < 2")
#    value
#beta   
#0     30
```

or:

```
df[df.index < 2]
# value
#0   30
```